# What does huba mean in this Polish Catholic marriage record?

Tags: marriage-records, palaeography, poland, catholic-church, latin

I got my hands on a marriage record from Poland.

[image]

It's written in Latin. Here's what I divined with the help of [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#la/en/Inter%20Josephem%20Wojnowski%20viduam%20de%20Bialybrod%20operanium%20et%20Hedwigam%20Wojteckam%20de%20huba%20Lukowo%20non%20uxor%20atam%20ad%20contrahendum%20matrimonium%20sacramentale%20benedictio%20Ecclesiae%20facta.):

> Inter Josephem Wojnowski viduam de Bialybrod operanium et Hedwigam Wojteckam de huba Lukowo non uxor atam ad contrahendum matrimonium sacramentale benedictio Ecclesiae facta.

Which means roughly

> Among Josephus Wojnowski widow of Bialybrod operating and Hedwiga Wojtecka of huba Lukowo, not his wife, contract this marriage, a sacramental blessing of this church.

My question is what the word `huba` is and what it means. It precedes the name of the bride's village. I thought maybe it would be village, city, or town but it's not any of those. `huba` doesn't appear to be a Latin word. It does mean `mouth`, `fungus`, or `mushroom` in Slovak, but that's clearly not relevant to this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some small differences, especially in word endings:

> Inter Josephum Wojnowski viduus de Bialybrod operanium et Hedwigem
>   Wojleckem de huba Lukowo non uxor atam ad contrahendum matrimonium
>   sacramentale benedictio Ecclesiae facta.

Translated, again small differences:

> Between Joseph Wojnowski, widower of Bialybrod, laborer, and Jadwiga
>   (or Hedwig) Wojlecka, of the estate of Lukowa, not his wife, to
>   contract a marriage, a sacramental blessing of the church

Huba is not Latin, but (probably) latinized German*, related to 'Hube' [old land measure] and 'Hof' [estate or land-parcel]. Used above to distinguish the estate of Lukowa, from the other Lukowas, of various sizes and administrative status, in the region.

*possible that there are Polish words derived from similar roots

Comment: Indeed, this has persisted in several villages names: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huby

Comment: @skolima I believe that the "Huby" you have linked to is derived from the name of a mushroom. Such village names are very common here.